# How do they make PCB with 0.2mm tracks?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I want to understand how do they make PCBs with 0.2mm tracks. I have built PCB using screen printing process. As screen print requires 0.5mm minimum track thickness, I need to keep track wider. Earlier I have ordered PCB online whose tracks thinner and not touching other tracks too. Can someone please help? I am attaching sample PCB which I want to build. [image]

Comment: Your title says 0.1 mm, but the first line in the question says 0.2 mm. The answer, however, is the same. They are etched after photoresist is applied. The smaller the trace, the more careful the process must be controlled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Simple: they don't use a screen-printing process.

Comment: With all due respect, the fact that you have to keep to a much more coarse "resolution" when screen printing does not imply that a professional manufacturer has the same limitations. They have financial incentives to have proper control and fine tune their processes - in a different manner than what a hobbyist has. (I assume you're a non-pro, if you were a professional PCB-manufacturer I wouldn't expect you knew as little about your process). Also: Why do you assume they do screen printing at all?

Comment: PCBway has a nice step by step illustration of the production process of a PCB. 
https://www.pcbway.com/capabilities.html